# Codeigniter HMVC and standart Codeigniter controllers

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3, hmvc, codeigniter-hmvc

I have admin module (**modules/admin**) with controller admin (**modules/admin/admin**).

I need put new controllers of admin to Codeigniter controllers folder (application/controllers/admin/new_controller), but when i go to site.com/admin/new_controller – 404. Why I need it? I want to admin module was every customer the same, but the other controllers must be unique for each project, thats why I need to put new controllers to **application/controllers/admin/** folder.

Is it possible to do this?

Codeigniter 3 and Wiredezignz HMVC (https://bitbucket.org/wiredesignz/codeigniter-modular-extensions-hmvc)

Comment: I think it is best to keep HMVC controllers in modules

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I don't know if it's the right decision, but I change name of folder: `application/controllers/admin to admin_unique`

and add to **application/configs/routes.php** two lines, example:

```
$route['admin/(login|logout|index|settings|users)'] = 'admin/admin/$1';
$route['admin/(.*)'] = 'admin_unique/$1';
```